# TikZ: positioning label at the end of a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, paths

I'm trying in TikZ to find a general way to draw an arrow and label it at the end.  Something like this works reasonably well:

```
\draw[->] (0, 0) -- (1, 3) node[pos=1.1]{$\vec{v}$};
```

However, depending on the orientation, if the label is too long, then the label can overlap the arrow:

```
\draw[->] (0, 0) -- (3, 0) node[pos=1.1]{$\vec{v} + \vec{w}$};
```

What I would ideally like is, for the latter arrow, the left side is at pos=1.1.  I know I can do this in this specific case by using `node[pos=1.1, anchor=west]`, but I'm looking for something more general (so that I could abstract this all and define a command to do it automatically).

One approach I considered was trying to find the width and height of the label and move the label using those values. So, 2 questions: Is there a way to find the width/height?  Or, alternatively, is there a better approach?

Comment: Hi Janet, welcome to the site! Do you want the length of the arrow to be fixed, as it is in your example? Or would you be happy with placing the nodes first, and drawing the arrow afterwards? That approach would be much easier.

Comment: Note that it wouldn't be enough to find the height and width of the node, you'd also need the orientation of the line pointing at the node, so you know in which direction to shift the node.

Comment: Is a relative position (`1.1`) the best here? That way the distance between the end of the line and the node differ for different line lengths.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For straight lines (`--`) a special `to path` could be the solution.

I have defined three `to` styles:

1. `a=<node text>`: relative positioning

   - `a position=<pos amount>` (default `1.1`)
2. `aa=<node text>`: absolute positioning

   - `aa distance=<length>` (default `1ex`)
3. `bb`: absolute positioning but saves the coordinate and the angle for later use:

   - `\xVecN`: the *x* value,
   - `\yVecN`: the *y* value,
   - `\aVecB`: the `anchor` angle.
   - The `bb style` uses these values internally.
   - `aa distance=<length>` (default `1ex`)

The lines in the code sample that are marked with `% debug` can be removed; they are only there to show how the styles work.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newlength{\qrrAadistance}
\setlength{\qrrAadistance}{1ex}
\newcommand*{\qrrAposition}{1.1}
\tikzset{
    a style/.style={% this style should be set to further change the behaviour of the nodes that are now hidden inside
        draw, % debug
    },
    a position/.code={\pgfmathsetmacro\qrrAposition{#1}},
    a/.style={% relative position
        to path={
            let \p1=(\tikztostart),
                \p2=(\tikztotarget),
                \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
              -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes node[pos=\qrrAposition, anchor=\n1-180, a style] {#1}
                                              node[pos=\qrrAposition, fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.6pt] {}% debug
        }
    },
    aa distance/.code={\pgfmathsetlength\qrrAadistance{#1}},
    aa distance/.initial=1ex,
    aa/.style={% fixed distance
        to path={
            let \p1=(\tikztostart),
                \p2=(\tikztotarget),
                \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)} in
              -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes node[anchor=\n1-180, a style] at ($(\tikztotarget)+(\n1:\the\qrrAadistance)$) {#1}
                                              node[fill=black, circle, inner sep=0.6pt] at ($(\tikztotarget)+(\n1:\the\qrrAadistance)$) {} % debug
        }
    },
    b/.style={% later usage
        to path={
            let \p1=(\tikztostart),
                \p2=(\tikztotarget),
                \n1={atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1)},
                \p{node}=($(\tikztotarget)+(\n1:\the\qrrAadistance)$)
                 in
              -- (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
              \pgfextra{\xdef\aVecN{\n1-180}\xdef\xVecN{\x{node}}\xdef\yVecN{\y{node}}}
        }
    },
    bb style/.style={
        anchor=\aVecN,
        at={(\xVecN,\yVecN)},
        a style,
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (0, 0) to[a=$\vec{v}$] (1, 3);
\draw[->] (0, 0) to[aa=$\vec{v} + \vec{w}$] (3, 0);
\draw[->] (0, 0) to[bb] (1, -3);
\node[bb style] {$\vec{v} + \vec{w} + (0, -6)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### `% debug`

#### How it works

```
\foreach \angle in {0,2,...,358}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-2.5,-2) -- (2.5,2);
\draw[->] (0, 0) to[aa=$\vec{v} + \vec{w}$] (\angle:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

#### Difference between absolute and relative positioning

```
\foreach \l in {0.1,0.2,...,2.9,3.0,2.9,...,0.2}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) -- (0:4.5cm);
\draw[->]              (0, 0) to[a =$\vec{v} + \vec{w}$] (0:\l);
\draw[yshift=-.7cm,->] (0, 0) to[aa=$\vec{v} + \vec{w}$] (0:\l);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

#### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware that anchor could take an angle, so that is good to know.  But you're right that absolute positioning makes more sense, and I like that better.  One small typo in the code above for anyone else following along: b/.style should be bb/.style

Comment: Great answer! Is there any way to get the same to work for curved paths?

Comment: Just found out: One can add the node at the end as a decoration, and use ```\pgfdecoratedangle``` to get the anchor angle for the end. No calculation and needed, and it also works for curved paths.