# How to draw a point at a given arclength along a curve in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider following example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) arc (0:90:1 and 2);
\filldraw (0,0) circle (2pt);
\filldraw[red] (-.1,.9) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Given a curve and an origin (A in the example), I would like to place a point on the curve at a given arclength from the origin (B at an arclength 1 in the example).

How can I achieve this? I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519225/equally-spaced-points-along-curve-with-associated-coordinates) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56347/how-to-draw-a-point-at-a-particular-location-along-the-curve-in-tikz), but do not see how to specify the arclength.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done (approximately) with `decorations.markings`, which accepts lengths (as well as percentages) for its `position`.

[image]

All markings in the image are at `1cm`.

Define a style `arclen` that takes a length as its argument. Then `\draw[arclen=1cm] <path>` will make the mark at `1cm` from the start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings}

\tikzset{arclen/.style={decoration={markings, mark=at position #1 with{\filldraw[red] (0,0) circle (2pt);}},
    postaction=decorate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray!50, very thin](0,-1) grid (-2,2);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) arc (0:90:1 and 2);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) arc (0:180:1);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) arc (0:270:.5);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) arc (0:330:.4);
\draw[arclen=1cm] (0,0) arc (0:330:.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Really interesting, especially if we know that the length may be defined by an integral not expressed by elementary functions.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke the “curve” is really a sequence of line segments. So there’s no integral involved. Just a sum. I suspect that if you tried this on a segment with large curvature you would see some inaccuracies. But I haven’t looked at the raw code to see how tikz calculates the number of points.

Comment: This is so nice, I didn't know it, thanks Sandy. +1

Comment: @SebGlav: Glad I could show you something new for a change. It's usually the other way around.