# How can I circumvent this TikZ circuits bug when placing symbols at start or at end?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bugs, tikz-circuit-lib

In the following MWE (essentially taken from page 603 of the [`pgf`](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=pgf) manual), when I try to place the symbols `at start` and `at end`, two unintended effects occur:

1. In each symbol there is an extra line extending from its center to its edge.
2. The the `to` path connects to the left side of the symbol `at end`. (I assume that TikZ "forgets" to transform the symbol coordinate system in order to make its `x` axis align with the path.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,circuit]
    \draw (0,0) to [circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=rectangle,near start},
        circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=circle,near end}] (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,circuit]
    \draw (0,0) to [circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=rectangle,at start},
        circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=circle,at end}] (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

There is [a bug report](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/412) about this issue. It is, however, from early 2017 which does not make me hopeful that this will be fixed in the near future.

Since I need to typeset documents *now*: Is there a way for me to fix this locally while preserving the TikZ syntax? (I would like the drawings to be able to be typeset with TikZ once the bug is fixed.)

Comment: How about `\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape,circuit]
    \draw (0,0) to [circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=rectangle,pos=0.05},
        circuit handle symbol={draw,shape=circle,pos=0.95}] (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}`? I am not sure I would call this a bug. After all this is a circuit and you are essentially moving stuff out of it.

Comment: @marmot: I absolutely disagree. Placing a symbol at the end of a path does not mean placing it outside a circuit. `ground`, for example, only ever makes sense at the end of a path. However, your comment led me to tinker around a bit and I found that `pos=1.0` works (while `pos=1` does not). I don't know why this is, but it is just the workaround I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
The Bug has been fixed in the latest release of `pgf` (version 3.1.3).

---

*[Original answer]*

I do not know why, but

```
\tikzset{
    at start/.style={pos=0.0},
    at end/.style={pos=1.0},
}
```

seems to solve the problem. (The original definition is with `pos=0` and `pos=1`.)

Comment: How is that conceptually different from [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489801/how-can-i-circumvent-this-tikz-circuits-bug-when-placing-symbols-at-start-or-at?noredirect=1#comment1236833_489801)? And I would never overwrite the standard Ti*k*Z definitions.

Comment: Well, in your comment you suggested to place the symbol close to (but not at) the start/end of the path. It turned out that one can actually correctly place a symbol at the end of a path by saying `pos=1.0` instead of `pos=1`. I think those are conceptually different assertions. I still believe this to be a bug (after all `1.0` should not be treated differently here than `1`; indeed the default definition expects `1` to work).

Comment: Regarding your concern about overwriting standard definitions: While I agree in principle, in this particular case (replacing `0` with `0.0` and `1` with `1.0`) I am not very worried at all. (Though in general an `append style` would be safer, of course.)

Comment: OK, let's agree that we disagree with each other's judgement. I made a proposal that works, you say that you do not like the numerical values I used. (My proposal was also motivated by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431765/121799.) Not much I can do. You say there is a bug, I do not see that. You say that replacing the integers by floats should be fine, but at the same time you see that this can have important consequences. I guess each of us can defend their view, so it is best if we depart peacefully. ;-)

Comment: You do not have to agree with me, of course. But maybe this example will help you understand: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\foreach \p [count=\i] in {0.9, 0.95, 0.99, 0.999999, 1, 1.0} {
\draw (\i,0) node [above] {\p} to[resistor={near start}, ground={pos=\p}] (\i,-3);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` If you still see no bug and still propose using a numerical value close(ish) to 1, then I guess we disagree.

Comment: Yes, I disagree, i.e. I think there is no bug, and if I would have written the answer I would have given credit to the above comment of mine. IMHO the point is very simple: a tangent is not well defined at the ends of the interval, which is why I made [the above proposal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/489801/how-can-i-circumvent-this-tikz-circuits-bug-when-placing-symbols-at-start-or-at/489845?noredirect=1#comment1236833_489801) in the first place. IMHO you are complaining that Ti*k*Z does not draw a proper tangent at the ends of the interval.

Comment: @marmot The problem here was that in [`tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/6b796ef15b4c6a1199dcff14d1db040d8fec4877/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/circuits/tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex#L56-L73) there is an extra code path for `pos=0.0` and `pos=1.0` which was not taken if you omitted the decimal place, so I decided that it is a bug.

Comment: @HenriMenke Fine with me. Is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/431753/121799) then a bug, too?

Comment: @marmot Yes, this is the reason why there are two code paths in `tikzlibrarycircuits.code.tex` but the one you linked might be much harder to fix.  You should open a ticket with MWE.